# Facebook app request dialog box keep on loading/busy

Tags: facebook, dialog, fb.ui

We have a facebook app and our app uses facebook app request dialog very frequently. Most of the time it works pretty well without any error and hick ups, but sometime the FB.ui dialog just keeps on loading and doesn't show the request that it needs to send. 
When such condition occurs wherever the FB.ui dialog is used, it behaves the same and it just keeps on loading. 
Interesting thing is that after few hours it starts to work correctly itself (without making any changes)

Each of our team member has a web application server running on their local machine and we all use the same facebook app id. Whenever the scenario occurs, it is visible on each development machine.

Has anybody scene such problem ?

Answer (score 3):

Finally we are able to find a solution for this problem. Following are the the points we pen down to work on:

1. The problem was visible on each machine where we were running local servers.
2. We created a new facebook app (basically new app id )  to test the behavior and it was the same result with the new app too.
3. We have one common demo server where we never noticed such a problem ( this server has different app id) .

we made changes in the setting of our server and moved it to port 80 from 8080 and everything started to work perfectly.

I don't understand how come the port number on server can cause problem for javascript code.

But the good news is after spending complete one day on this bug we are back on development track.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I am experiencing the same bug. The Facebook developers don't seem to test their own code. They keep introducing new bugs in the production environment EVERY day!! You never know when things work.

http://www.lazerwire.com

Comment: We found one solution for this problem. Please look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the problem is the port. On port 80 it works, on port 8080 (which we use for development, localhost:8080 but also stagingserver:8080) FB dialogs does not work anymore. Got no idea why.

Comment: did you get the solution before us or after us ? though hardly matters   now as it is solved. About your last statement, that's really weird how a client side javascript doesn't work because of this content was generated through port 8080. Probably we should fire this as bug to facebook ( if possible)

Comment: Hi Pankajanand, I discovered this by myself, cause it was working in production but on our development machines, but since I found it to bee too strange to be true, I searched for it and found this question. It is "solved", but not really : we still have troubles in development and staging machines, where we don't have everything on port 80, and should not be forced to use port 80 for some mysterious FB reason.

Comment: Simone, I understand such problems exist in the big environments .. One of my friend has the same issue and he solved through by running the server on 8080 port only but he routed all traffic of port 80 to 8080. I am not sure that this will be helpful for you or not. Regards,Pankaj Anand

Comment: Hi Pankaj Anand, thanks for you suggestion. We did something similar for a few days, then it seems like Facebook fixed it. Our main problem was running automated tests, cause the machine that runs continuous integration works also as a maven repository and port 80 was already taken. However, seems like Facebook solved it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using to parameter to pass the list of friends. Just don't pass more then 25 friend ids for example.

This happens to me when passing 50 friends to apprequest dialog. When passing 25 it works fine.

Not sure what is the magic number, tried 26 and still works.

I got an idea to try to lower number of friends because of the IE6/IE7 25 friends per request limitation.