# FB.ui callback not called / FB.ui stream publish loading forever

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

This recently working perfectly code no longer works properly when in usage with FB JS API:

```
placeOrder : function(order_info) {
  var onOrderPlaced = function(data) {
    if (data['order_id'] && data['status'] == 'settled') {

      window.FLASH.flashObject.artifactAdded(order_info);

      return true;
    } else {
      // handle errors here
      return false;
    }
  };

  window.fbAsyncInit();

  // calling the payment dialog
  try {
    FB.ui({
      method : 'pay',
      order_info : order_info,
      purchase_type : 'item',
      dev_purchase_params : {
        'oscif' : false
      }
    }, onOrderPlaced);
  } catch (err) {
    // TODO handle payment error
  }
}
```

The order takes place and is processed perfectly, but what does not happen afterwards, for like several days, the callback function, onOrderPlaced is never called upon payment completion. As I said, several days ago this functionality was working flawlessly.

Another problem I encountered is prompting FB.ui with stream.publish method. All I see is the iframe and the loading animation within and it takes forever. Another functionality that worked flawlessly several days ago. And now it's not working. Anyone experiencing the same issues?

Comment: Please point to a full code sample, or to a url where this can be seen.

Comment: @SeanKinsey that piece of code above is the full sample of the issue with the callback not being called. The FB.ui call with method 'pay' is being called, processed and when finished, onPlaceOrder not being called (something that worked few days ago)

Comment: no that has no mention of FB.init, it has no info about the url, the init data etc..

Answer (score 1):

about: "Another problem I encountered is prompting FB.ui with stream.publish method. All I see is the iframe and the loading animation within and it takes forever"

Yes, since yesterday I am having the same issue.  I don't know what can be.

Comment: check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032605/facebook-app-request-dialog-box-keep-on-loading-busy

Comment: thanks bud, I've already suspected FB developers of not testing production code

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue where our FB.ui JS callback recently stopped working.  As suggested in Edwin's linked issue, we switched the server to run on port 80, and callbacks are being called again.  I've filed a bug with Facebook.  Thanks for the linked answer - we were very puzzled by this behaviour!