# Requests dialog not closing

Tags: facebook, user-interface, dialog, modal-dialog

I have been using the requests dialog quite happily up until this morning when it has stopped working correctly.
When submitting the dialog or cancelling it, the dialog becomes stuck and does not close and therefore not call it's callbacks. It just sits there, blank, doing nothing.

image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2o0rW.png

Any ideas what the problem could be or how to fix it? Or is this just another case of wait for Facebook to fix their code and roll it out?

Thanks

Update:
Similar to this issue [Facebook app request dialog box keep on loading/busy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032605/facebook-app-request-dialog-box-keep-on-loading-busy)

Changing the server port to 80 fixed the issue.

Comment: I have just set up an entirely new app and the same is happening there also.

Comment: Also, this happens in multiple browsers. Chrome, Firefox and Safari on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also experiencing this issue -- I created a new app with a Site URL that points to my non-standard port and it made no difference (in my case I'm seeing the auth dialog not closing because the callback is never received).

Temporary workaround: create an ssh tunnel from port 80 to your non-standard port.  You'll have to do that as root if you're on a unix box, of course.

I've filed a bug with Facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/276500519124789