# Facebook request dialog that not stop loading in live server

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, multi-friend-selector

Am developing a facebook application. There is a functionality to send multifriend app request. When some one tap on multifriend link multfriend popup window appears and they can select friend and send invite. Every thing works perfect in my local server. When i upload the same code to live server, the facebok request dialog that not stop loading. Its not loading friends list also. Am not getting any errors in my console. 
Please see the loading window 
[image]

```
function multifriend_request(userfullname,checkedgame){
    //var userfullname = {ldelim}$userfullname{/ldelim};
    console.log('user full name',userfullname,checkedgame);
    FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests',
        title:'Freunde für Bewerbung FC Bayern-Bus auswählen',
        message:"Mit BAYERN 3 und dem FC Bayern-Bus ins Stadion!\n"+
        userfullname+" bewirbt sich mit seinen Freunden um 11 exklusive Plätze zu einem Heimspiel des\n"+
        "FC Bayern München in der Allianz Arena - inklusive Transfer im FC Bayern-Bus."

    }, callbackmultifriend_request);
}
```

I found a thread in stack [Facebook app request dialog box keep on loading/busy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032605/facebook-app-request-dialog-box-keep-on-loading-busy)
but not sure about the issue. Please help me to solve this issue, Thanks

Comment: I've seen this before in cases where I was proxying through Charles on production sites that were SSL secured.  You using a proxy, or are on SSL?

Comment: Am not integrated the app to facebook, still testing with server itself. Yet to buy an SSL for the domain. Testing with my domain http://fcbbus.brainpirates.de/. Sorry i dont have much idea about the proxy settings you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this, it was my mistake, just changed my app settings to my live server address. Earlier it was local server address. Now its working great.Thanks